# Bootstrap Month-Year Picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I need to add a couple of month-year pickers to a form that I'm creating in a Bootstrap template. I have found a plugin to do exactly what I need, however it was written in an older version of jQuery and therefore breaks... I can't roll back to a previous version as it will break other plugins on the page.

What I need is here: http://techbrij.com/month-range-picker-jquery-ui-datepicker
It's a simple way to enter a date range using only month/year options. It will be used to select periods of employment. Can anyone steer me in the right direction to migrate this to jQuery 2.1.*?

EDIT 2016-02-08
It seems that the conflict lies with my bootstrap template. The template I'm using is AdminLTE by Almsaeed Studio

This is what gets rendered after following all the steps to load jquery/jquery-ui
[image: Render]

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I am assuming that you are using the same html, css, and JavaScript from the link provided as there is none posted in your answer.

Answer (score 3):

It appears to work fine, I reconstructed an example using the following script url's for Jquery(version 2.1.3) and JqueryUI(version 1.11.2). Make your you are including both in a script tag right before your closing `</body>` tag. The original code is from an online article at http://techbrij.com/month-range-picker-jquery-ui-datepicker.

cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js

cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js

Live Example: http://codepen.io/larryjoelane/pen/jWeVPE

HTML:

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
 <label for="from">From</label>
 <input type="text" id="from" name="from" readonly="readonly" />
 <label for="to">to</label>
 <input type="text" id="to" name="to" readonly="readonly"  />
 <input type="button" id="btnShow" value="Show" /> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.ui-datepicker-calendar {

    display: none;

   /*use the line below instead to override existing css*/
   /*display:none !important*/

}
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#from, #to").datepicker({
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  showButtonPanel: true,
  dateFormat: 'MM yy',
  onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
    var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
    var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
    $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
  },
  beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
    if ((datestr = $(this).val()).length > 0) {
      year = datestr.substring(datestr.length - 4, datestr.length);
      month = jQuery.inArray(datestr.substring(0, datestr.length - 5), $(this).datepicker('option', 'monthNames'));
      $(this).datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
      $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
    }
    var other = this.id == "from" ? "#to" : "#from";
    var option = this.id == "from" ? "maxDate" : "minDate";
    if ((selectedDate = $(other).val()).length > 0) {
      year = selectedDate.substring(selectedDate.length - 4, selectedDate.length);
      month = jQuery.inArray(selectedDate.substring(0, selectedDate.length - 5), $(this).datepicker('option', 'monthNames'));
      $(this).datepicker("option", option, new Date(year, month, 1));
    }
  }
});
$("#btnShow").click(function() {
  if ($("#from").val().length == 0 || $("#to").val().length == 0) {
    alert('All fields are required');
  } else {
    alert('Selected Month Range :' + $("#from").val() + ' to ' + $("#to").val());
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Larry, please see my edit - it appears there is a conflict with the bootstrap template that I'm using.

Comment: Can you post the css for the template in your question?

Comment: I don't have your template css but you might try the css over ride I added to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The code seems to work fine in JQuery 2.1.4 with JQuery-UI 1.11.4: https://jsfiddle.net/sLfga1jt/3/

Have you verified that your script tags are loading and in the proper order? Jquery script reference should be before Jquery-UI.

Also verify that the javascript from http://techbrij.com/month-range-picker-jquery-ui-datepicker is loaded after the script references by including in a script tag after jquery (as shown in example) or by wrapping in the document ready or similar function to ensure code is run after all the scripts are loaded:

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
    <label for="from">From</label>
    <input type="text" id="from" name="from" readonly="readonly" />
    <label for="to">to</label>
    <input type="text" id="to" name="to" readonly="readonly"  />
    <input type="button" id="btnShow" value="Show" /> 
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $( "#from, #to" ).datepicker({ 
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: 'MM yy',            
        onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
            var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
            var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();             
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
        },
        beforeShow : function(input, inst) {
            if ((datestr = $(this).val()).length > 0) {
               year = datestr.substring(datestr.length-4, datestr.length);
               month = jQuery.inArray(datestr.substring(0, datestr.length-5), $(this).datepicker('option', 'monthNames'));
               $(this).datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
               $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));    
            }
            var other = this.id == "from" ? "#to" : "#from";
            var option = this.id == "from" ? "maxDate" : "minDate";        
            if ((selectedDate = $(other).val()).length > 0) {
               year = selectedDate.substring(selectedDate.length-4, selectedDate.length);
               month = jQuery.inArray(selectedDate.substring(0, selectedDate.length-5), $(this).datepicker('option', 'monthNames'));
               $(this).datepicker( "option", option, new Date(year, month, 1));
            }
        }
    });
    $("#btnShow").click(function(){ 
        if ($("#from").val().length == 0 || $("#to").val().length == 0){
            alert('All fields are required');
        }
        else{
            alert('Selected Month Range :'+ $("#from").val() + ' to ' + $("#to").val());
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, please see my edit - it appears there is a conflict with the bootstrap template that I'm using.